# Change Order Status Magento by Customer

Tags: xml, magento, content-management-system, e-commerce

i'm new with Magento Development. Is there anyway the Customer can **change his order status in My Order details** within his account?If so, which would be the steps of doing so? Any help i'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way provided by magento to do so, but this is strange functionality anyone would want to their e-store. Please can you clarify why would you want to do this instead the admin controlling the order status of the customers?

Comment: This is because the order may be changed by the admin and the customer must accept or reject the new order changing its cuatom status to ..lets say.. Accepted or Rejected